# SPFx - Cannot add sharepoint framework webPart in list NewForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx-webparts, newform

I want to add my custom sharepoint framework webpart form add list item in default add page in my list. 
I have following error after add webpart in NewForm.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the details about the error in the ULS log for further research.

Then check if there is error in your custom SharePoint framework web part.

Create a new page and add the custom SharePoint framework web part to check the result.